# Display Time Constantly For Custom HTML5 & jQuery Video Player

Tags: jquery, html, css

When I first load my page containing my custom embedded Video Player I made, the elapsed & total time doesn't display. But, when I play the video it shows up. Could anyone help me out and tell me what I could be doing wrong, please. Thank you!

**Example Picture:**

**What the Video Player looks like when page first loads:**
[image: What the Video Player looks like when page first loads.]

**What the Video Player looks like when played:**
[image: What the Video Player looks like when played.]

**HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Video Player - HTML5</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/video_player.css">
</head>
<body>
    <section id="main">
        <video id="videoPlayer" width="640" height="480">
            <source src="video/test.webm" type="video/webm"></source>
            <source src="video/test.ogv" type="video/ogv"></source>
            <source src="video/test.mp4" type="video/mp4"></source>
            This is a video for html5 browsers.
        </video>

        <nav id="vidControls" class="clearfix">
            <div id="playPauseBtn" class="left">Play</div>
            <div id="scrubberContainer" class="left">
                <div id="scrubberBar"></div>
            </div>
            <div id="timer" class="left">
                <span></span>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </section>

    <!-- JAVASCRIPT -->
    <script src="js/jquery-2.0.3.js"></script>
    <script src="js/VideoPlayer.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            VP.init();
        });
    </script>
    <!-- END JAVASCRIPT -->

</body>
</html>
```

**CSS:**

```
html, body {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    width: 100%;
}

article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section { 
    display: block;
}

.left {
    float: left;
}

.right {
    float: right;
}

.clearfix:after {
    content: ".";
    display: block;
    clear: both;
    visibility: hidden;
    line-height: 0;
    height: 0;
}

.clearfix {
    display: inline-block;
}

#main {
    width: 720px;
    margin: 20px auto;
    padding: 12px;
    background: #CCC;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-box-shadow: 2px 5px 5px #888;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 2px 5px 5px #888;
    box-shadow: 2px 5px 5px #888;
    /* For IE 8 */
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(Strength=5, Direction=135, Color='#888')";
    /* For IE 5.5 - 7 */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(Strength=5, Direction=135, Color='#888');
    /* For Non-CSS3 Browsers */
    background: #EBF1F6;
    /* For IE */
    filter: 
        progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#F3F4F5', endColorstr='#DADADA');
    /* For WebKit Browsers */
    background: 
        -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#F3F4F5), to(#DADADA));
    /* For Firefox 3.6+ */
    background: 
        -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #F3F4F5,  #DADADA);
}

nav {
    margin: 5px;
    width: 100%;
}

#timer {
    display: block;
    color: #000;
    text-align: center;
    height: 28px;
    padding-top: 12px;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-family: Arial;
}

#playPauseBtn {
    display: block;
    background: #656565;
    color: #FFF;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 9px;
    border: 1px solid #DADADA;
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 64px;
}

#playPauseBtn:hover {
    background: #FFF;
    color: #333;
}

#playPauseBtn:active {
    background: #333;
    color: #999;
}

#scrubberContainer {
    position: relative;
    width: 500px;
    height: 20px;
    padding: 4px;
    margin: 6px;
    background: #000;
}

#scrubberBar {
    position: absolute;
    background: #FF6600;
    width: 0px;
    height: 20px;
}
```

**Javascript:**

```
var VP = VP || {};

var barSize = new Number(500);
var scrubberContainer = $('#scrubberContainer')[0];
var scrubberBar = $('#scrubberBar')[0];
var playPauseBtn = $('#playPauseBtn')[0];
var videoPlayer = $('#videoPlayer')[0];
var updatePlayer;
var updateTimer;

VP.init = function(){
    playPauseBtn.addEventListener('click', VP.togglePlayPause, false);
    scrubberContainer.addEventListener('click', VP.scrubberClicked, false);
    videoPlayer.addEventListener('timeupdate', VP.updateTimer);
}

VP.togglePlayPause = function(){
    if(!videoPlayer.paused && !videoPlayer.ended){
        videoPlayer.pause();
        $('#playPauseBtn').html('Play');
        window.clearInterval(updatePlayer);
        window.clearInterval(updateTimer);
    } else {
        videoPlayer.play();
        $('#playPauseBtn').html('Pause');
        updatePlayer = setInterval(function()
        {
            VP.updateScrubber();
        }, 100);
    }
}

VP.updateScrubber = function(){
    if(!videoPlayer.ended){
        var size = parseInt(videoPlayer.currentTime * barSize/videoPlayer.duration);
        $('#scrubberBar').css('width', size + 'px');
    }
    else{
        $('#scrubberBar').css('width', '0px');
        $('#playPauseBtn').css('Play');
        window.clearInterval(updatePlayer);
    }
};

VP.scrubberClicked = function(e){
    if(!videoPlayer.paused && !videoPlayer.ended){
        var mouseX = e.pageX - scrubberContainer.offsetLeft;
        var newTime = mouseX * videoPlayer.duration/barSize;
        videoPlayer.currentTime = newTime;
        $('#scrubberBar').css('width', mouseX + 'px');
    }
};

VP.updateTimer = function(){
    var eTime;
    var tTime;

    //calculate elapsed time
    var eSeconds = Math.round(videoPlayer.currentTime);
    var eMinutes = Math.floor(eSeconds/60);
    eMinutes = (eMinutes >= 10) ? eMinutes : "0" + eMinutes;
    eSeconds = Math.floor(eSeconds % 60);
    eSeconds = (eSeconds >= 10) ? eSeconds : "0" + eSeconds;

    //calculate total time
    var tSeconds = Math.round(videoPlayer.duration);
    var tMinutes = Math.floor(tSeconds/60);
    tMinutes = (tMinutes >= 10) ? tMinutes : "0" + tMinutes;
    tSeconds = Math.floor(tSeconds % 60);
    tSeconds = (tSeconds >= 10) ? tSeconds : "0" + tSeconds;

    //assign these values to our variables
    eTime = '' + eMinutes + ':' + eSeconds;
    tTime = '' + tMinutes + ':' + tSeconds;

    //display in timer
    $('#timer').html('' + eTime + ' / ' + tTime);
};
```

Comment: There's no time there because the video file hasn't been opened at that point.  It can only show you the time once the video has started playing.  Alternatively, if you know the time (either manually or by some server code), you can display it yourself.

Comment: @Archer How can I make the video open once the page loads without it actually playing?

Comment: Not sure if this would work, but you could call a `play()` and then a `pause()` immediately after.

Comment: @Archer I don't understand what you mean? Could you explain a little more, please?

Comment: Can you make a jsfiddle, or do you have a link?

Comment: @Archer http://jordansimpson.comoj.com/heritage/videoplayer/videoPlayer.html

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit scrappy, and there may be a better way to do it when the html5 video player evolves, but it works for me anyway.  Just put this at the end of your `document.ready` code...

```
$("#videoPlayer")[0].play();
setTimeout(function() {
    $("#videoPlayer")[0].pause();
}, 100);
```

It starts the video playing and then stops it 1/10th of a second later.  The person viewing the page shouldn't notice anything and it gives it enough time to show the play info for the video.

Comment: This works perfectly with Firefox and Safari, but for IE and Opera it shows up as "00:00 / 0NaN:0NaN" when the page loads. When I click play it acts normal while using IE and Opera. Thanks for all your help, by the way.

Comment: No worries mate - glad to help :)  Try increasing the timeout in increments of a hundred to see if you can fix IE and Opera.

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML must have the data too.

```
        <span id="currentTime">00:00</span> / <span id="durationTime">00:00</span>
```

And maybe is good to put something like this

currentTime.innerHTML = formatTime(seconds);

where format time is your function();
And seconds the variable where is stored your video data, in this case the seconds.

This is what i did.

```
    video.addEventListener("timeupdate", function() {





            function formatTime(seconds) {
        minutes = Math.floor(seconds / 60);
        minutes = (minutes >= 10) ? minutes : "0" + minutes;
        seconds = Math.floor(seconds % 60);
        seconds = (seconds >= 10) ? seconds : "0" + seconds;
        return minutes + ":" + seconds;
      }




                      var seconds = video.currentTime;





        currentTime.innerHTML = formatTime(seconds);


        });




    video.addEventListener("timeupdate", function() {





        function formatTime(seconds) {
    minutes = Math.floor(seconds / 60);
    minutes = (minutes >= 10) ? minutes : "0" + minutes;
    seconds = Math.floor(seconds % 60);
    seconds = (seconds >= 10) ? seconds : "0" + seconds;
    return minutes + ":" + seconds;
  }




                  var seconds = video.duration;





    durationTime.innerHTML = formatTime(seconds);


    });
```

//AND IN THE HTML THE FOLLOWING

```
<span id="currentTime">00:00</span> / <span id="durationTime">00:00</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

@Verde Mc your answers are all good. But, it lacks the var keywords which will make the code not to work.
Just do this:

```
    video.addEventListener("timeupdate", function() {
  function formatTime(seconds) {
    var minutes = Math.floor(seconds / 60);
    minutes = (minutes >= 10) ? minutes : "0" + minutes;
    var seconds = Math.floor(seconds % 60);
    seconds = (seconds >= 10) ? seconds : "0" + seconds;
    return minutes + ":" + seconds;
}

var seconds = video.currentTime;
currentTime.innerHTML = formatTime(seconds);
});




video.addEventListener("timeupdate", function() {
function formatTime(seconds) {
    var minutes = Math.floor(seconds / 60);
    minutes = (minutes >= 10) ? minutes : "0" + minutes;
    var seconds = Math.floor(seconds % 60);
    seconds = (seconds >= 10) ? seconds : "0" + seconds;
    return minutes + ":" + seconds;
}
var seconds = video.duration;
durationTime.innerHTML = formatTime(seconds);
});
```